# How upgrade varchar(8000)?

Tags: sql-server

I wand to upgrade my varchar(8000) to more data(I mean , I want to increase 8000) what I will do for this?

Hoping for your support.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On SQL Server 2005 and up, you can upgrade to VARCHAR(MAX) (up to 2 GB of data):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
   ALTER COLUMN YourColumn VARCHAR(MAX)
```

That should do it.

Comment: if i use this  , exixting data will loss or no?

Comment: The existing data will be fine :)

Comment: No, you will not loose any data - your field just now supports 2 GB instead of 8000 characters of data.

Comment: i getting an error The statement has been terminated. Msg 9002, Level 17, State 4, Line 1 The transaction log for database 'newdb' is full. To find out why space in the log cannot be reused, see the log_reuse_wait_desc column in sys.databases

Comment: Your DB log file is full you can truncate it with BACKUP LOG <yourdatabasename> WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY if sql 2005; if 2008 see next comment... 

Before changing the table defn; how many records are in the table? It may be quicker to move the records to a new table with the new definition and then drop the original table; finally rename the new table to old.

Comment: alter database <mydb> set recovery simple
go

checkpoint
go

alter database <mydb> set recovery full
go

backup database pubs to disk = 'c:\mydb.bak' with init
go

dbcc shrinkfile (N'mydb_log' , 1)
go

Comment: Yup, that's *not* a problem with the statement, but a problem with your database transaction log. It fills up quite a bit when you do these kind of updates. Put your database into simple mode - do the updates - then go back to "Full" backup mode.

Answer (score 0):

With version 2005 or 2008 you could use varchar(max).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx

Answer (score 0):

From SQL Server 2005 and upwards, you can use `nvarchar(max)`.  For earlier versions, you can use `text`.